# ASP.NET MVC with JSON REST Webservics

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm from Java background, but have been given a ASP.NET MVC RESTful services project to work on. I need some guidance as to where to start.

I have a web service running on the server that returns JSON data. I've to build a MVC system to consume the data including user login, account creation, and basic CRUD operations.

I'm confused about how to connect the model to the web service?

How can I connect to it using MVC? DO I have to use Web API? I've watched few tutorials, but to no avail so far. Any suggestion for the tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this tutorial will do what you are looking for

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

with web apis you have a few options. the above sample is a simple way of doing it.

you can also use Angular JS or knockoutjs or my favorite one is using breeze js.

***Adding more information about how to connect model to the web service***

in the above example, in thr Adding a model section:

Class product is being created :

```
    public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

this class is the blue print of our model

we fill this model in the Controller ( Controller is responsible for managing our model and introduce it to the view)

So product class being filled here

```
 Product[] products = new Product[] 
    { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };
```

The main point is our controller should be inherited from  ApiController.

```
 public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
```

The above two methods are getting data from our model and returning data.

and at the end our javascript file is responsible for reading the data by using  $.getJSON .

so to answer your question. how connecting model to web services. the answer is in the methods in controllers.

this is a very simple sample. in real-world data needs to be read from database with using entity framework

this sample shows how to do it

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thanks for the reply, appreciated. It misses though on the main culprit for me, connecting model to the web service or how to consume that web service in MVC.

Comment: I tried to expand my answer although this is a very broad area. let me know if you have any problem with your application. send us more detailed problem we will be happy to help. I suggest start developing and on each piece of work where you have problem send your code, the guide will come to you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I'll comeback once I hit a roadblock. A quick question though, in the example, products are getting created in the code like 'new Product { Id = 1, ....', in my case, all data is coming from JSON web service. When I tried instantiating web service in the controller, at runtime I get a runtime error for 'Could not find default endpoint element that references contract'  ... any ideas?

Comment: I think this is what you looking for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25141/consuming-an-asp-net-web-api-call-in-an-mvc-controller  or http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/209/consuming-feeds-and-web-services-in-razor-web-pages    or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834930/calling-a-json-api-from-my-controller-instead-of-from-the-view-in-my-asp-net-mvc